# Angular 2 / SystemJS Dependencies

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have a fairly straightforward question regarding importing node modules into my angular app. I have added these node modules to my package.json, and I have simply set up an app according to the angular 2 quickstart guide.

Whenever I try to import a node module in app.component.ts, it is unable to find it resulting in a 404 in the browser. However, once I add the necessary maps and other config options to SystemJS, it find the node module and loads it. However, it seems that for each dependency, I have to find out the location of its main js file, and add that to SystemJS. As I have a ton of node module dependencies I would prefer not to do so.

Is there an example SystemJS configuration that can just automatically load the necessary node modules or do I have to spell out each and every single node module's mapping in the systemjs config file to set this up...?

Comment: Are you on visual studio?

Comment: nope, just using the exact setup from here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: I would look into using webpack instead of systemjs. It is much simpler and more complete. Adding other modules is easier as well. They have a guide for it here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html